# How to disable code signing requirement

Tags: iphone, code-signing, archiving

After getting email for invalid binary from Appstore, fixed issue now trying to archive again, Xcode is giving error that code signing is required for product type Application' in SDK iOS 5.1.

So how can i disable this code signing.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Are you trying to resubmit an updated application to the app store? If so, you will need to code-sign the updated binary.

Comment: yes i updated application so need to archive updated app. But how to code sign it because in code signing section don't see provision profile for distibution.

Comment: You'll need to set up a profile, if you haven't already done so. Presumably something exists already, if you're updating an existing app. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2250/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

Disable code signing when using `xcodebuild` by setting the `CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY` build setting to an empty string:

For example:

```
xcodebuild build \
  -project 'bikestreets-ios.xcodeproj' \
  -scheme 'BikeStreets' \
  -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 15' \
  CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=""
```

Answer (score -1):

In file  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/SDKSettings.plist

change the 
CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED
YES

to

CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED
NO

Restart Xcode