# Remove codesign from iOS framework

Tags: ios, iphone, frameworks, code-signing

I have build an iOS framework and it is working fine with adhoc and development profiles but appStore submission is getting failed due to codesign errors. Is there any command like:

> `lipo -remove codesign`

to remove codesign from my Framework? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30449529/how-to-disable-code-signing-in-ios-xcode-6-3 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20875927/how-to-undo-codesign https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691979/how-to-disable-code-signing-requirement

Comment: Thank you for the related links but all of 3 above links are not related to Frameworks. I tried this command _ codesign --remove-signature_ but it says invalid or unsupported format for signature.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this ?

Comment: @PushpaRaja, I know its very late but yes, please check my Answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone still face this issue then following was my solution:

1. Build 1st framework for device and 2nd framework for simulator
2. Strip off the simulator slices of 2nd framework by using `lipo -info` to see the simulator architecture, then remove them using commands

   lipo -remove x86_64 MyFrameWork -o MyFrameWork

   lipo -remove i386 MyFrameWork -o MyFrameWork
3. Remove the codesign of 1st framework by following step 2
4. Use `lipo` to create universal iOS framework from previous both framework. this universal framework can be used in the project which will be codesign under that project and no issue in submitting to the AppStore.